# Why the function when loaded doesn't give any output?

Tags: r

Here I have defined the function `CpG.T.Test` and inside it I am running the *t*-test. But at the end, neither `t` nor `p` exist.

```
CpG.T.Test  <- function(betam, pheno){
  R = 50000
  t = numeric(R)
  p = numeric(R)

  for (i in 1:R){
    beta.v <- betam[i, ]
    pheno.v <- pheno

    test <- t.test (beta.v ~ pheno.v)
    t[i] = test$statistic
    p[i] = test$p.value
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to add a `return` to it knows what to return

Comment: the function is actually on the last line--if the for loop was replaced with `sapply`, there _would be_ a return value. technically this is more of a "why does this for loop return null" question than a duplicate of the one linked question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to return 2 variables, you can combine them into a single dataframe and return it as follows:

```
CpG.T.Test  <- function(betam, pheno){
  R = 50000
  t = numeric(R)
  p = numeric(R)

  for (i in 1:R){
    beta.v <- betam[i, ]
    pheno.v <- pheno

    test <- t.test (beta.v ~ pheno.v)
    t[i] = test$statistic
    p[i] = test$p.value
  }

  cbind(t,p) # the last variable used in the scope is usually returned.
  ## OR
  ## return cbind(t,p) # or you can explicitly return the variable
}
```